# AWS CodeCommit code review tool with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, version-control, aws-codecommit

I would like recommendations integrating code reviews into our development process. We use AWS CodeCommit integrated with visual studio. There doesn't seem to be any way to leverage CodeCommit pull requests through visual studio. Any recommendations or best practices are helpful